# Incorrect grouping in for-each-group

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML from which I am trying to generate HTML files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
    <body>
        <milestone unit="fragment"/>
            <div>

                <p>First line text in FIRST fragment</p>
                <p>Second line <seg>text in FIRST</seg> fragment</p>
                <p>Third line text in FIRST fragment</p>

                <milestone unit="fragment"/>
                <p>First line text in SECOND fragment</p>
                <p>Second line <seg>text in SECOND </seg> fragment</p>
                <p>Third line text in SECOND fragment</p>

                <milestone unit="fragment"/>
                <p>First line text in THIRD fragment</p>
                <p>Second line <seg>text in THIRD </seg> fragment</p>
                <p>Third line text in THIRD fragment</p>

            </div>
    </body>
</text>
```

Expected HTML Output:

```
HTML 1:
<p>First line text in FIRST fragment</p>
<p>Second line <span>text in FIRST</span>fragment</p>
<p>Third line text in FIRST fragment</p>


HTML 2:
<p>First line text in SECOND fragment</p>
<p>Second line <span>text in SECOND </span> fragment</p>
<p>Third line text in SECOND fragment</p>

HTML 3:
<p>First line text in THIRD fragment</p>
<p>Second line <span>text in THIRD </span> fragment</p>
<p>Third line text in THIRD fragment</p>
```

This is the XSLT where I am using for-each-group to group the nodes between "milestone" tags, but the grouping does not occur as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" name="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" include-content-type="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::*" group-starting-with="milestone[@unit='fragment']">

            <xsl:variable name="currFragNumber">
                    <xsl:number count="milestone[@unit='fragment']" level="any" from="text"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:result-document href="{$currFragNumber}.html" format="html">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
                </xsl:result-document>

        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="seg">
        <span>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the output after of the transform.

```
HTML 1:
<p>First line text in FIRST fragment</p>
<p>Second line <span>text in FIRST</span>fragment</p>
<p>Third line text in FIRST fragment</p>

<p>First line text in SECOND fragment</p>
<p>Second line <span>text in SECOND</span>fragment</p>
<p>Third line text in SECOND fragment</p>

<p>First line text in THIRD fragment</p>
<p>Second line <span>text in THIRD</span>fragment</p>
<p>Third line text in THIRD fragment</p>

<p>First line text in FIRST fragment</p>
<p>Second line <span>text in FIRST</span>fragment</p>
<span>text in FIRST</span>
<p>Third line text in FIRST fragment</p>


HTML 2:
<p>First line text in SECOND fragment</p>
<p>Second line <span>text in SECOND </span> fragment</p>
<span>text in SECOND </span>
<p>Third line text in SECOND fragment</p>

HTML 3:
<p>First line text in THIRD fragment</p>
<p>Second line <span>text in THIRD </span> fragment</p>
<span>text in THIRD </span>
<p>Third line text in THIRD fragment</p>
```

I am trying to understand why the first current-group()(i.e. first "milestone") is matching the whole document rather than just the nodes between the "milestone" tags.

Comment: Replace `descendant::*` by `milestone|div/*`

Comment: I can't see any reason why you should get this output from this input. Which XSLT 2.0 processor are you using?

Comment: Am testing this with Saxon-HE 9.2.1.5J and Saxon-HE 9.3.9.4(built-in with Oxygen XML 12.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are also selecting the `div`, as I've suggested in comments.

Use:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="div/*" 
                    group-starting-with="milestone[@unit='fragment']">
```

It will correctly serialize three result documents. Do note that you could just forget the first `milestone` because according to http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group

> If the `group-starting-with` attribute
>   is present, then its value must be a
>   pattern. In this case, the items in
>   the population must all be nodes.
>
> The nodes in the population are
>   examined in population order. If a
>   node matches the pattern, **or is the
>   first node in the population**<sup>*</sup>, then a
>   new group is created and the node
>   becomes its first member. Otherwise,
>   the node is assigned to the same group
>   as its preceding node within the
>   population.

<sup>*: emphasis is mine.</sup>

Comment: @Alejandro The solution of using `div` will work only for cases where there is a `div` inside `body`. But for cases like **[this](http://www.pastie.org/1702977)** where there is no `div` it will not do the correct grouping. The only work around I found is to use `select="div/*"` `when` div is present, `otherwise` use `select="*"`/

Comment: @Jahangir: Any solution is just for a clearly defined use case. If there would be documents with `div` and documents without it, that should be in your question's requeriments. Then you must redefine what elements you want to group, for example `descendant::p` or `descendant::* except div`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: In my initial reply (below) I thought that the value of the `select` attribute was required to be a pattern and now I see that I was misled by the spec.

In this case, the reported behavior is most likely a bug.

@Jahangir, congratulations for discovering a bug in at least three XSLT 2.0 processors.

---

**The W3C XSLT 2.0 spec says** (about the `select` attribute of `xsl:for-each-group`):

> "•If the group-starting-with attribute
>   is present, then its value must be a
>   pattern."

And the rules for pattern allow only the `child::` or `attribute::` axes to be used in the pattern.

**Therefore, `descendant::*` is not allowed as a pattern**. I guess that the XSLT processor treats this as "recoverable error" and takes its own action as recovery.

The solution is to put the first `milestone` element in its proper place as the immediate following sibling of `div`, and change the `select attribute of`xsl:for-each-group`to:`div/*`:

```
<text>
    <body>
        <div>
        <milestone unit="fragment"/>
            <p>First line text in FIRST fragment</p>
            <p>Second line 
                <seg>text in FIRST</seg> fragment
            </p>
            <p>Third line text in FIRST fragment</p>
            <milestone unit="fragment"/>
            <p>First line text in SECOND fragment</p>
            <p>Second line 
                <seg>text in SECOND </seg> fragment
            </p>
            <p>Third line text in SECOND fragment</p>
            <milestone unit="fragment"/>
            <p>First line text in THIRD fragment</p>
            <p>Second line 
                <seg>text in THIRD </seg> fragment
            </p>
            <p>Third line text in THIRD fragment</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</text>
```

and:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" name="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" include-content-type="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="div/*" group-starting-with="milestone[@unit='fragment']">

            <xsl:variable name="currFragNumber">
                    <xsl:number count="milestone[@unit='fragment']" level="any" from="text"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:result-document href="{$currFragNumber}.html" format="html">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
                </xsl:result-document>

        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="seg">
        <span>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The problem is that the source XML file is much more complex than shown here and it doesn't have a standard structure(E.g.[1](http://www.pastie.org/1702972), [2](http://www.pastie.org/1702977), [3](http://www.pastie.org/1702985). The tricky part is the grouping when the `group-starting-with` (i.e. milestone[@unit='fragment']) pattern is nested inside multiple levels.

Comment: I'm confused, because the group-starting-with pattern as shown doesn't use the descendant axis. Perhaps it has been edited?

Comment: @Michael I was just pointing out to Dimitre that the problem arises when the source XML file is much more complex(like this **[one](http://www.pastie.org/1703490)**) and the `group-starting-with` pattern is nested inside multiple levels. Even if I use `descendant::*` or `div/*` in the `select` attribute of for-each-group I do not get the expected grouping.

Comment: @Michael-Kay: No, it doesn't. I was misled by the XSLT 2.0 spec (the bullets) to think that the requirement to be a pattern is for the value of the "select" attribute -- now I see that this (and the bullets) does not make sence and the pattern requirement is most probably for the value of the `group-starting-with` attribute itself. In this case I cannot explain the behavior (though this is common for all XSLT 2.0 processors I have) and this seems like a bug. What do you think?